# Why Spring MVC can't get session from redis

Tags: spring-mvc, session, redis, spring-session

I use SpringSession+redis, it can save the session to redis,but I cant't get the session attribute the when i call "${sessionScope.user.name}" in jsp

this is web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

this is applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- spring data redis -->
<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="6379"></property>
    <property name="password" value="123456"></property>
    <property name="database" value="0"></property>
    <property name="usePool" value="true"></property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate" id="redisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- spring session -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
```

this is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(String name, String pwd,HttpSession session){
    User user=new User();
    user.setName(name);
    user.setPwd(pwd);
    session.setAttribute("user",user);
    return "forward:/success.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping("test")
public String test(HttpSession session){
    //there,session.getAttribute("user")=null ???
    return "forward:/test.jsp";
}
```

When i request the project, I can see the session has been saved in Redis
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8owvu.png)

but when I request test.action ,It can't get the Seesion Attribute.
What's wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that in your `test` handler method the session id is the same as it was in previous request that was handled by `login` handler?